# Aplicar una clase por algunos segundos (JAVASCRIPT o ANGULAR)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

Tengo una tabla con objetos.
Cada objeto tiene una hora y minuto asociada (a su ultima modificación).

Ilustrativo algo así:

[image: Imagen ilustrativa]

Me gustaría que si es la misma misma hora. Se aplique un color a toda la fila (durante 5 segundos).

Estuve probando algunas cosas para intentar añadir y quitar clases despues de 5 segundos con Javascript.

Por el momento tengo esto:

```
 <tr #row *ngFor="let order of orders; index as i" (onload)="getIsNew(order,row)" [ngClass]="{...}">
```

Mi idea era que al cargar le agregue la clase `'is-new'` a la `#row` y a los 5 segundos quitarsela.

El problema es que directamente no ingresa a la funcion `getIsNew()`.

Seguramente esté haciendo algo mal con el evento (onload) desde Angular.

---

La segunda opción fue usar [ngClass].
De tal manera quedaba así:

```
<tr #row *ngFor="let order of orders; index as i" [ngClass]="{'is-new': getIsNew(order,row)}">
```

donde `getIsNew() es esta función:`

```
getIsNew(order: Order, row:any):boolean{
  return order.dataOfcreation.hour == this.date.getHour();
}
```

el problema es que permanece la clase 1 minuto entero (la comparación de las horas es HH:MM). No me gustaría agregar los segundos a estas horas.

Comment: ¿Y en qué parte establece la duración en un minuto?

Comment: Me equivoqué al expresarme.
El cambio impacta en lo que quede de minuto.
Porque detecta la ultima modificación y compara con la hora actual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la clase `.is-new` podrías agregar una animación que espere 5 segundos para quitar el color de fondo de la fila:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        .is-new {
            background-color: red;
            animation: example 0.5s forwards;
            animation-delay: 5s;
        }

        @keyframes example {
            100% {
                background-color: unset;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <tr class="is-new">
            <td>dato 1</td>
            <td>dato 2</td>
            <td>dato 3</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Eso me ayuda, me da una base muy grande con lo que quiero hacer. El problema surge con background-color: unset. Quita el color que tenía antes y si le asigno el color que tenía antes, directamente no me modifica el color.

Comment: Bueno. Logré hacerlo. Solamente setee al momento del 0% el color que quería. Muchas gracias.